# Metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Definition:

- We first define three different metrics on $\mathbb R^2$: $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_1)$, $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_2)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_\infty)$ with
  $$d_1(x, y):=|x_1 −y_1|+|x_2 −y_2|$$
  $$d_2(x, y) := {\sqrt{(x_1 − y_1)^2 + (x_2 − y_2)^2 }}$$
  $$d_\infty(x, y) := \max{|x_1 − y_1|, |x_2 − y_2|}$$
  where  $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and  $y=(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

What we've already proved:

- For all $x,y  \in \mathbb{R}^2$,
  $$d_\infty(x, y) 
  \le d_2(x, y) 
  \le d_1(x, y) ≤ \sqrt{2} 
  d_2(x, y) ≤ 2 
  d_\infty(x, y)$$
- A sequence $(a_n, b_n)$ converges to $(a, b) \in\mathbb{R}^2$ for the distance $d_\infty(x, y)$ if and
  only if $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively converge to $a$ and $b$.

What we're looking for :

- We want to show that  $(a_n, b_n)$ converges to $(a, b) \in\mathbb{R}^2$ for the distance $d_\infty(x, y)$ if and only if $(a_n, b_n)$ converges to $(a, b) \in\mathbb{R}^2$  for the distance $d_1(x, y)$, if an only if
  $(a_n, b_n)$ converges to $(a, b) \in\mathbb{R}^2$  for the distance $d_2(x, y) $.
- We also want to show that open sets for $d_\infty\\$ are open for $d_1\\$ and for $d_2\\$.

Any hints please?

Comment: It is not quite clear what is what here, what is given, or what is asked. Try reformulating the question.

Comment: Please define $d_{\infty}$, $d_{1}$, and $d_{2}$.

Comment: My edit was  for typos: $a_n$ for $an$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with [strong equivalence of metrics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics).

Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ be metric spaces and suppose it was given that there exists constants $A,B >0$ such that $$Ad_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq Bd_1(x,y)$$ for all $x,y\in X$. Now, Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $X$ and $x\in X$.

**Claim:** $x_n\to_{d_1} x$ $\iff$ $x_n\to_{d_2} x$, where "$\to_{d} x$" means "converges to $x$ with respect to $d$".

*Proof:*  We have that
$$0 \leq d_1(x_n,x) \leq \frac{1}{A} d_2(x_n,x)$$
and 
$$0 \leq d_2(x_n,x) \leq Bd_1(x_n,x).$$
Therefore
$$d_1(x_n,x) \to 0 \iff d_2(x_n,x)\to 0,$$
that is
$$x_n\to_{d_1} x \iff x_n\to_{d_2} x.$$